# How to print tree on pdf in java?

Tags: java, printing, tree, trie

I am trying to print a prefix tree, I already modeled the trie class, I need to print the prefix tree something like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15iYz.png)

But I can't figure out how to create it in a perfect way, I'm using the iTextPdf library, but I've only made the Root node, but when trying to create the next one I can't center the text, divide the page or something similar, I wanted to know if any of them have a best solution or have any idea to do it. Thank you

Comment: Have you try Jasper Studio?

Comment: No KMS, i don't try

Comment: You can use Jaspersoft iReport for your task.